# Why isn't my iPod touch's calendar showing up in iCloud?

Tags: ipod-touch, icloud

I have enabled iCloud for my iPod touch and enabled Calendar sync, but my calendar events aren't showing up in iCloud when I login, even after I've manually backed it up to iCloud. What's the problem?

Comment: What version of iOS is your iPod touch running? Did you do your iCloud configuration from within Mac OS X or iTunes, or from within the system settings on the iPod touch?

Comment: @Wheat It's running iOS 5. I set up iCloud from the iPod touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with an iPad Calendar that wouldn't sync with [e.g., appear on] my other devices.

I found this link helpful:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=13675190&postcount=9

In my case, I turned off iCloud Calendar syncing on the iPad [in iCloud settings].  I then chose to *keep* the Calendar data on the iPad rather than delete it.

Next, I turned iCloud Calendar syncing back on in iCloud settings, chose Merge, and bingo, everything appeared everywhere.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this worked. Thanks for your answer!